# ACPI Error on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, acpi

I have a Lenovo T550 I've installed ubuntu 18.04 on.

Here is the `uname -a` output:

```
5.4.0-050400-lowlatency #201911242031 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 25 01:44:43 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The lowlatency build is installed due to this problem occurring in both 5.3 generic 5.4 generic and this one. Well, not this specific problem but an other one. And this one has been persistent amongst all of the kernel versions.

The ACPI error in question is as follows:

```
[     0.508911] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000000d942e14c (20190816/exresop-66)
[     0.508911] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20190816/dswexec-424)
[     0.508911] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

This error appears on startup. The screen first goes that Ubuntu background dark red color, then turns pure black displaying this error. Then turns dark red again and then briefly flashes something else. It happens so fast I'm unable to tell if it's just this error again. Then the Ubuntu login appears.

I've observed others having similar problems on different linux distros and with various computer types, though lenovo seems to have a nack for this error.

As far as I've been able to research, there has been no solution to this problem other than some people experienced when upgrading to a more recent Fedora version. The problem disappeared but would catch up as the distros became outdated. As such I can't find a fix and the threads that take up this issue simply fall off into obscurity.

Can anyone help? Tell me if you need any readouts.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to check out my BIOS to see if there might have been something wrong there. Though it was updated I found that due to a lock on the laptop, the BIOS was set to legacy first setup. This meant that Ubuntu was installed in legacy format. I reset the option to UEFI only then reinstalled Ubuntu.

All my errors and issues are now gone.

Answer (score 0):

My BIOS on HP computer had a firmware upgrade pending. After upgrading BIOS, the error went away.